# Recording Commands Run by a User on RHEL5

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel, pam, linux-audit

I am trying to use **pam_tty_audit** to record every commands run by a user. I SSH into the RHEL5 host and run `sudo -i` and then appended

`session    required     pam_tty_audit.so disable=* enable=root`

to the beginning of `session` section of the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` files as shown in [this example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_PAM_for_Auditing.html#sec-configuring_pam_tty_audit). Then I restarted `auditd` service. After this, I randomly ran `pwd` and `ls` commands for testing purpose. Then I typed `aureport --tty` to check if there are any commands recorded. But it seemed no commands were recorded as the CLI output was something like:

```
TTY Report
===============================================
# date time event auid term sess comm data
===============================================
<no events of interest were found>.
```

Do you have any suggestion, thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `script` ?

Comment: @Rahul Thanks, I didn't try `script` yet. After googling around, I found `auditd` is supposed to be a decent way to solve my original problem.

Comment: have you set audit rules for users ?